# How reject incomming calls using AT-commands in simcom module a76xx (a7672e)

Tags: embedded, at-command

On the sim800/900 modules, this was done using the AT+GSMBUSY=1 command. Please, help me.

I need incoming calls not to interfere with me and could not intercept control that was in the other work processes.

What do I need to do? thank you in advance

Comment: Try to disconnect with `ATH`, that should probably work (btw, not very likely but note that `ATH` behaviour for voice calls is controlled with `AT+CVHU`. Mode 1 will ignore `ATH`,  mode 0 or 2 will disconnect). Alternatively you can try `AT+CHUP`.

Comment: Another alternative is to set up call forwarding (`AT+CCFC`),  which then tells the telephone network to not initiate an incoming call under some condition (which you want to be always (at least for some time)).